# Get ID of Table that contains a checkbox

Tags: javascript

I have many tables each one with an ID, (table1,2,3,...), and in each one I have many TD's `<td><a href`

example :

```
<table id="myTable1" class="someclass">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>blablabla</td>
      <td><a href="domaine.com">random text</a></td>
      <td><a href="domaine.com">randomtext</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</td>
<table id="myTable2" class="someclasse">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>blablabla</td>
      <td><a href="domaine.com">random text</a></td>
      <td><a href="domaine.com">randomtext</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</td>
```

(don't look at the HTML code it's not important for now )

My goal is to open all `href`s within the table "table X" then open them in new tab. I do that with

```
var els = document.getElementById("myTable1").querySelectorAll("a[href^='https://domaine.']");

for (var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i++) {
  var el = els[i];
  alert(el)
  window.open (el,"_blank");
}
```

It works like a charm. Now I want to add a checkbox to each table, and if checked to open the `href` on "the" table I checked (I did some `innerHTML` to "insert" checkbox). Now my question, how can I get the table ID when I'll check the checkbox?

For example I check the table that have "table6" and then every link in that table gets opened.

table id=1 (checkbox)

table id=2 (checkbox)
etc

if i check the checkbox it will get the table with id 2

Answer (score 0):

You can use [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to get the closest table, then you can get the id from that.

```js
// List of checkboxes
let inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]'))
// Add a click event to each
inputs.forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('click', e => {
    let target = e.currentTarget
    // If the checkbox isn't checked end the event
    if (!target.checked) return
    // Get the table and id
    let table = target.closest('table')
    let id = table.id
    console.log(id)
  })
})
```

```html
<table id="abc">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="def">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="ghi">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="jkl">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You say that you are adding the checkbox dynamically, so you won't want to do a `querySelectorAll` like I did above. You will want to add it when it is created like this:

```js
// List of tables
let tables = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table'))
// insert the checkbox dynamically
tables.forEach(table => {
  table.innerHTML = '<tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td></tr>'
  // Get the checkbox
  let checkbox = table.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]')
  // Add an eventlistener to the checkbox
  checkbox.addEventListener('click', click)
})

function click(e) {
  let target = e.currentTarget
  // If the checkbox isn't checked end the event
  if (!target.checked) return
  // Get the table and id
  let table = target.closest('table')
  let id = table.id
  console.log(id)
}
```

```html
<table id="abc">
</table>

<table id="def">
</table>

<table id="ghi">
</table>

<table id="jkl">
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! i have the answer and a good explanation   ! thanks again ! +1

Answer (score 0):

> …I want to add a checkbox to each table, and if [it's] checked…open the `href` [in] "the" table I checked…how can I get the table ID when I'll check the checkbox?

Given that you want to find the `id` of the `<table>` within which the check-box `<input>` is contained in order to select the `<table>` via its `id` property you don't need the `id`; you simply need to find the correct `<table>`.

To that end I'd suggest placing an event-listener on each of those `<table>` elements, and opening the relevant links found within. For example (bearing in mind that there are restrictions on opening new windows/tabs on Stack Overflow, I'll simply style the relevant `<a>` elements rather than opening them):

```
function highlight(e) {

  // here we find the Static NodeList of <a> elements
  // contained within the <table> element (the 'this'
  // passed from EventTarget.addEventListener()) and
  // convert that Array-like collection to an Array
  // with Array.from():
  Array.from(this.querySelectorAll('a'))

    // iterating over the Array of <a> elements using
    // Array.prototype.forEach() along with an Arrow
    // function:
    .forEach(

      // here we toggle the 'ifCheckboxChecked' class-name
      // via the Element.classList API, adding the class-name
      // if the Event.target (the changed check-box, derived
      // from the event Object passed to the function from the
      // EventTarget.addEventListener function) is checked:
      link => link.classList.toggle('ifCheckboxChecked', e.target.checked)
    );
}

// converting the Array-like Static NodeList returned
// from document.querySelectorAll() into an Array:    
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table'))

  // iterating over the Array of <table> elements:
  .forEach(

    // using an Arrow function to pass a reference to the
    // current <table> element (from the Array of <table>
    // elements to the anonymous function, in which we
    // add an event-listener for the 'change' event and
    // bind the named highlight() function as the event-
    // handler for that event:
    table => table.addEventListener('change', highlight)
  );
```

```js
function highlight(e) {
  Array.from(this.querySelectorAll('a'))
    .forEach(
      link => link.classList.toggle('ifCheckboxChecked', e.target.checked)
    );
}

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table')).forEach(
  table => table.addEventListener('change', highlight)
);
```

```css
body {
  counter-reset: tableCount;
}

table {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid limegreen;
}

table::before {
  counter-increment: tableCount;
  content: 'table' counter(tableCount);
}

a.ifCheckboxChecked {
  background-color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td><a href="#">cell 1</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">cell 2</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">cell 3</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td><a href="#">cell 1</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">cell 2</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">cell 3</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td><a href="#">cell 1</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">cell 2</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">cell 3</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td><a href="#">cell 1</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">cell 2</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">cell 3</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ncn6qocL/1/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [`::before` pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)
  - [Using CSS Counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`Element.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: Thank you very much ! i have the answer and a good explanation   ! thanks again ! +1